# MySQL/MariaDB: unable to make changes with correct permisions and user. NOT A PASSWORD PROBLEM

Tags: mysql, permissions, mariadb

getting some odd behaviour with my remote connexion to the db.  user table looks like this:

```sql
+-----------+-----------+
| host      | user      |
+-----------+-----------+
| %         | manage    |
| %         | remoteusr |
| 127.0.0.1 | root      |
| ::1       | root      |
| localhost | root      |
+-----------+-----------+
```

running `select current_user();` gives me this:

```sql
+----------------+
| current_user() |
+----------------+
| manage@%       |
+----------------+
```

and `show grants;` gives me this:

```sql
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for manage@%                                                             |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'manage'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '-REDACTED-' |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

so for all intents, this should allow me to do whatever the hell i want from wherever the hell i connect.  but when i try to create a new user, this is the error i get:

```sql
MariaDB [thing_db]> grant all privileges on thing_db.* to 'remoteusr'@'%';
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'manage'@'%' to database 'thing_db'
```

totally stumped here.  based on [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connection-access.html), there is no alternate permission that could be authenticated against.  when i `select user()`, i get `manage@localhost`, which should still allow me to do what i need as there is no empty `@locahost` in the user table.

this seems a pretty straightforward thing and i've `flush privileges;` several times to no effect.

so what the heck is going on here that i'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have all permissions apart from the `GRANT` priv, meaning you cannot grant privileges to other user. See `WITH GRANT OPTION` from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html).

Comment: ...you've got to be kidding... *slap*.  doesn't the `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES...` include actual GRANT privileges??  i used to enumerate them, but started using the ALL keyword...  how do i actually GRANT GRANT???

Comment: nm.  sorted.  had to use `GRANT GRANT OPTIONS...`.  thank you so much.  feel like a twit... but that's ok.  problem sorted.